# split chunk array from bigger array

Tags: javascript

i have an array like this

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

i am trying to make sub arrays from this main array so that it will look something like this

```
const splitArray = [[1,4], [2,5], [3,6], [7]];
```

what i have tried so far is

```
const convertToSubArray = (array, chunkSize = 2) => {
  let i, j, accum = [];

  for (i=0, j=array.length; i<j; i+=chunkSize) {
      accum = [...accum, array.slice(i, i+chunkSize)];
  }

  return accum;

}
```

But getting this as the output

```
[
    [
        1,
        2
    ],
    [
        3,
        4
    ],
    [
        5,
        6
    ],
    [
        7
    ]
]
```

How can i achieve this, any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the logic behind the expected result? Why 1-4, 2-5 etc

Comment: it should pick 2 items after the selected one

Comment: So then shouldn't it be `[1, 4, 7]`? This logic doesn't make sense. Can you explain further?

Comment: sorry i mean if 1 is selected then the next item should after 2 positions of current so which will be 1 & 4

Comment: What is the desired result when chunk size = 3? Also, I assume you would want to take the length of the array into consideration, and that no items should be repeated in the desired output, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a group of six items as `offset` and inside of each group of six take another offset build by the half of items (`p`) in this group.

```text
 p    indices        grouping                    comment
---  -------------  --------------------------  --------------
 3    0 1 2 3 4 5    [[0, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5]]
 3    0 1 2 3 4      [[0, 3], [1, 4], [2]]
 2    0 1 2 3        [[0, 2], [1, 3]]
 2    0 1 2          [[0, 1, 2]]                 special case
 1    0 1            [[0, 1]]                    "
 1    0              [[0]]                       "
```

At iterating check if the last index in the group is odd, then take a a single value instead of a pair of values.

```js
const
    chunk = array => {
        const result = [];

        for (let offset = 0; offset < array.length; offset += 6) {
            const l = Math.min(array.length - offset, 6);

            if (l <= 3) {
                result.push(array.slice(offset, offset + 3));
                break;
            }

            for (let i = 0, p = Math.ceil(l / 2); i < p; i++) {
                result.push(i + 1 === p && l & 1
                    ? [array[offset + i]]
                    : [array[offset + i], array[offset + i + p]]
                );
            }
        }

        return result;
    };

console.log(chunk([1]));
console.log(chunk([1, 2]));
console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4]));
console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));
console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));
console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]));
console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, But this is failing when we have  data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: in the second the first array is 1 & 5 which means its taking 3 items skipping ideally it should skip only two items

Comment: this approach works only when chunkSize = 2 (this is default), what about when `chunkSize=3`.

Comment: [
  [
    1,
    4
  ],
  [
    2,
    5
  ],
  [
    3,
    6
  ],
  [
    7,
    9
  ],
  [8 ]  
]

Comment: @NinaScholz hope you understood like till 6 its a group after that next group starts

Comment: it should check whether 2 elements i can skip then it should or else whatever the minimum

Comment: its a dual list where the ranking happens, so the raw data 1,2,...n numbers. so each section consist of 6, how does that 6 happens is 1 + array[index + 2] => so which will be 1 & 4 then 2 & 5 then 3 & 6 like wise so that one set is done. now next set will be another 6 since already till 6 taken it starts from 7 & 10 then 8 & 11 then 9 & 12
in a case if 7,8,9 only there then it will be 7 & 9 and 8

Comment: [[1,4] [2,5], [3,6], [7,8]] => because after a set of 6 only remaining is 7 & 8

Comment: so main conditions are of 6, and max 2 of element skipping if not possible then whatever its there remaining clubbed

Comment: @NinaScholz Any ideas how to achieve this, as i am stuck on this logic, several approach tried but didn't worked :(

Comment: you need to define, what you want for 6 to 1 elements for all other larger arrays, you take a multiple of six and the rest, but the rest is a problem, you may enlight.

Comment: do you want for 5 elements this (numbers are indices) `[[0, 3], [1, 4], [2]]` or `[[0, 2], [1, 3], [4]]`?

Comment: @NinaScholz i hope this will be the values in that case [1] => [1]
[1,2] => [1,2]
[1,2,3] => [[1,3], [2]]
[1,2,3,4] => [[1,4], [2,3]]
[1,2,3,4,5] => [[1,4], [2,5], [3]]
[1,2,3,4,5,6] => [[1,4], [2,5], [3,6]]

Comment: @dev ... And for a real validity test of any provided implementation the OP still needs to provide some expected results for not just the `chunkSize` default value of `2` but also for at least the chunk size of `3`.

Comment: @NinaScholz so inshort if 3 elements are there then it should fill the three  [1,2,3] => [1,2,3] because one row is three and if more than three is there then it will start that clubbing logic

Answer (score -2):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
const splitArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i + 3] != undefined) {
    splitArray.push([arr[i], arr[i + 3]])
  }
}

console.log(splitArray);
```

Comment: Thanks, But 4 is repeating ideally last chunk array should be 7 only